# Movie with a killer robot/android in a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, androids

So I forgot the name of this movie but what I remember is the following:

- It happens in a spaceship.
- The robot/alien seems to be from another world.
- The robot/alien can transform to look like other people.
- I'm not sure if the robot was alien or if it was a malfunctioning robot they took with them.
- It didn't look like a robot initially—it looks like a human and could change the looks of his face to pretend to be other humans.
- The robot/alien was quite tough.

One crew member is trapped somewhere with radiation with another dead crewmember (I believe it was the cockpit). And then he has to crawl trough some really small space to do... something... open a door I think. So he basically sacrifices himself.

It didn't look as old as Saturn 3. It's probably just a bit newer (1985-90).

Comment: Hello and welcome to Scifi.SE. Please consider taking [the tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour). I hope somebody will be able to answer your question.

Comment: It's probably not [Saturn 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079285/) with Kirk Douglas, but just throwing this out here to jog your memory. (To make you say things like "no, it wasn't _that_ old" etc.)

Comment: Yeah its not Saturn 3. The robot I'm talking about had a head. Didnt look like a robot initially (it looks like a human and could change the looks of his face to pretend to be other humans)

and indeed it didnt look that old...its probably just a bit newer (85-90)...Come to think about it I'm not sure if the robot was alien or if it was a malfunctioning robot they took with them

Answer (score 2):

*[Project Shadowchaser III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Shadowchaser_III)* is a 1995 movie with a killer robot that can look human. I can't seem to find more details about the movie, but here's the trailer to see if it sparks some recognition.